# asp mvc viewmodel validation attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am using one ViewModel for two actions: create and update.
But field

> CommonFile

(with required attribute) is situated in Create view. So ModelState.IsValid is false in update action. How to use one modelview in this two views?

```
public class UnitViewModel
{   
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required field")]
    [StringLength(256, ErrorMessage = "SomeMessage")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string Code { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required field")]
    [DateAttribute(ErrorMessage = "Incorrect date format")]
    public string MapDeadline { get; set; }

    public int InAllCount { get; set; }

    public int LoadedCount { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required field")] 
    [FileAttribute(AllowedFileExtensions = new string [] { ".xls", ".xlsx" })]
    public HttpPostedFileBase CommonFile { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a CreateViewModel that inherits UnitViewModel

```
public class CreateViewModel : UnitViewModel 
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required field")] 
    [FileAttribute(AllowedFileExtensions = new string [] { ".xls", ".xlsx" })]
    public HttpPostedFileBase CommonFile { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an OO question. Create a BaseUnitViewModel that has everything but the CommonFile, then derive from it with the CommonFile for your method that needs it.

Answer (score 0):

although Bigfellahull's solution is a much better approach, In update action you can check the ModelError then if the error is related to field CommonFile, just ignore it.